# Phrase for high-performing element that 'raises the average'

Tags: phrase-requests

My question is about the situation where there's say a film which is poorly made and would leave a bad impression overall, were it not for the exceptionally good performance of one sole actor which compensates for all the other shortcomings.

One could say that that particular actor had *saved* what would have otherwise been a completely unsatisfactory production.

I'm looking for the correct phrase to express this. Please note that I am only using film as an example. In my native language, the same expression that can be applied to a good actor that makes an otherwise bad film bearable can be applied to any 'anomalously high-performing' element that 'compensates' for all the substandard elements in an ensemble.

Comment: _to save the situation_, maybe? Would you say someone _saved_ a certain  conference, or that a particular result _saves_ a certain thesis, though?

Comment: The *saving grace*, perhaps?

Comment: There are several, depending on how disproportionately better the element is and possibly the situation.

Answer (score 2):

**saving grace**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/saving-grace)

> A redeeming quality of something or someone.

AS in:

> The movie was bad, but made bearable by the **saving grace** of actor X.

Comment: alright I feel slightly poached

Comment: Thank you, it works well. Do you know how to put that in verb form? I may not have indicated this clearly in my original post, sorry for that.

Comment: @Unrelated i did not see your comment until after i had composed my answer and posted.

Comment: hard to put this idioms in a verb form.

Comment: In my language one would simply say _Actor X [lifts up from the ground] the movie_. Could you simply say 'Actor X _saved_  the movie' or would the meaning be lost on most people?

Comment: X's acting saved the movie

Comment: @ibf [smiley emoji]

Answer (score 2):

### carry

Based on one of @nuraxi's comments

> In my language one would simply say Actor X [lifts up from the ground] the movie.

we can get an almost exact translation

> Actor X ***carried*** the performance.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry):

> 15 : to be chiefly or solely responsible for the success, effectiveness, or continuation of
>
> a player capable of *carrying* a team
>
> Her performance *carried* the play.
>
> (mine) The battle was *carried* when a small squad took out several machine-gun emplacements on the right end, enabling a flanking maneuver.

Just a caveat, this is typically used when the standout element is a person, and as the definition shows, usually when the element results in an overall success.

On the other hand,

### silver lining

> a consoling or hopeful prospect

(again, from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silver%20lining)) can be used more generally, for efforts that aren't successes, or even complete disasters.

> Bartolo's 8 strikeouts in 3 innings of relief pitching for the Mud Hens proved to be the only silver lining in a 10-0 loss to the Dayton Flyers, as Toledo looks foward to a strong bullpen next year.

A [quote of John Milton's](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/every-cloud-has-a-silver-lining.html)

> Was I deceived, or did a sable cloud
> Turn forth her silver lining on the night?

evolved into the now well-worn proverb *every cloud has a silver lining*.

(by the way, *saving grace*, as other answerers have demonstrated, is another good answer in this latter context, so those answers deserve upvotes too).

Comment: "[Actor X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racer_X_(character))" is the secret older brother of "Speed Actor", and a better actor too, although X's actions to protect little brother usually result in the latter getting the accolades.

Comment: Very well explained! As you've said, _carry_ implies that the end result is a (resounding?) success. Can you use it when the end result may be anywhere between 'only just acceptable' and 'resounding success'?

Answer (score 1):

Two terms that may fit take a religious turn:

**saving grace**

> a redeeming quality or characteristic.

**redemption** (or more idiomatically, *redeeming quality* or *redeeming aspect*)

> a thing that saves someone from error or evil

Comment: Thank you, both are indeed fitting. Do you know how to put that in verb form? Could you say X _redeems_ the performance? Otherwise the only quibble I have is that I intend to address a secular(ist) and non-Christian audience and I'm not too sure using terms that sound 'obscurantist'  will go down too well (even though they may have long since lost their religious tone for native English speakers). Thanks again.

Comment: _redeeming quality/factor_ would work. Thanks @Unrelated for putting me on the right track.

Comment: You could definitely say “redeems” and do without any religious connection. Not obscure.

Comment: Saving grace is harder to make a verb and also more religious. @nuraxi

Answer (score 1):

One general idiom is to [save the day](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/save-the-day). The Cambridge dictionary gives the example

> The team seemed to be heading for disaster until a late goal saved the
>   day.

Here are some more examples. They are not exactly like what you asked, but you did say there is a general phrase in your language for similar circumstances.

> The debate was going badly until a key point raised from the floor
>   saved the day.
>
> The leading actor was taken ill but his understudy saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the phrase you are looking for is, “The only redeeming...”

redeeming
[ri-dee-ming]
adjective

1   offsetting or counterbalancing some fault, defect, or the like

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/redeeming)

> e.g.
>
> *“That film was awful, the only redeeming factor was the music.”*
>
> *”This car is junk, the only redeeming part is it costs nothing”*
>
> *”The person is a moron. Their only redeeming quality is that they are kind.”*